# Most correct way to join values from two formulas where each row from first formula needs to join all values from second formula and so on

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

The formula that is in `A1` to create the alphabet sequence is this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(char(row(A97:A122)))
```

The formula that is in `B1` to create the sequence of letters is this:

```
=SEQUENCE(10)
```

I would like to merge the two formulas into one formula, returning the following result:

```
a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
a6
a7
a8
a9
a10
b1
b2
b3
b4
b5
b6
b7
b8
b9
b10
c1
c2
c3
c4
c5
c6
c7
c8
c9
c10
... and so on
```

I'm currently doing it in the following way that logically doesn't unite the two formulas, but it's the only way I know how to do it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
A1&B1:B10;
A2&B1:B10;
A3&B1:B10;
A4&B1:B10
})
```

But to join the two formulas so as not to spend so many columns, this method would be too long and flawed, how to join the two formulas in a smart way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(CHAR(ROW(A97:A122))&SEQUENCE(1, 10)))
```